# Rails5: redirect user after sign-in not working properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a `devise` setup with 3 different users that have their own `sessions/registrations controllers` and their own `models` too.

I have also created the setup for the `after sign-in path`

```
 def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  case resource
    when Admin
      admin_index_path
    when Seller
      stored_location_for(resource) || seller_account_path(current_seller)
    when Buyer
      redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
   else
      permission_denied
   end
  end
```

The `admin and seller after sing-in path` work just fine, but when a `buyer signs-in` it returns this error:

```
AbstractController::DoubleRenderError in Buyers::SessionsController#create

Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action. Please note that you may only call render OR redirect, and at most once per action. Also note that neither redirect nor render terminate execution of the action, so if you want to exit an action after redirecting, you need to do something like "redirect_to(...) and return".
```

the error is at the `super` line inside the buyers `sessions_contoller.rb`

```
 def create
   super
 end
```

I'm trying to redirect the `buyer` to the same page!
Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this:
inside my `application_contoller.rb`

```
before_action :store_buyer_location!, if: :storable_location?


private
  def storable_location?
    request.get? && is_navigational_format? && !devise_controller? && !request.xhr?
  end

  def store_buyer_location!
    # :buyer is the scope we are authenticating
    store_location_for(:buyer, request.fullpath)
  end
```

and change the after sign in path for the buyer:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  case resource
    when Admin
      admin_index_path
    when Seller
      stored_location_for(resource) || seller_account_path(current_seller)
    when Buyer
      stored_location_for(resource) || super
   else
      permission_denied
   end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the `create` method on the `session` controller because you don't need to override this method because you have not any functionalities without `devise` default functionalities.

I don't' know how you define `Admin` `Seller` and `Buyer` if you create `method` for those then ok otherwise you can rewrite the `after_sign_in_path_for` method like below

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if resource.column_name == 'Admin'
        admin_index_path
    elsif resource.column_name == 'Seller'
        stored_location_for(resource) || seller_account_path(current_seller)
    elsif resource.column_name == 'Buyer'
        redirect_back(fallback_location: root_path)
    else
      permission_denied
    end
end
```

Hope it helps